# Joint distribution of the first and second repeat in a sequence of random numbers

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

I have iid random variables $Z_1,Z_2,...$ that are uniformly distributed on the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$. I define $X(n)=\min\{k:Z_k=Z_j\text{ for some }j<k\}$ and $Y(n)=\min\{k:Z_k=Z_j,Z_i=Z_l\text{ for some }j<k \text{ and }i<l<k\}$ so X(n) is the first repeat of a number and Y(n) is the second repeat (not necessarily a repeat of the same number as the first repeat.). I'd like to calculate the joint distribution and I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly:
$$P(X(n)\leq x, Y(n)\leq y)=P(Y(n)\leq y|X(n)\leq x)P(X(n)\leq x)$$
$$=P(X(n)\leq x)\sum_{j=2}^{x}\frac{P(Y(n)\leq y,X(n)=j)}{P(X(n)=j)}$$
$$=(1-\prod_{k=1}^{x-1}(1-\frac{k}{n}))\sum_{j=2}^{x}\frac{1-\prod_{i=j}^{y-1}(1-\frac{i}{n})}{\frac{j-1}{n}\prod_{k=1}^{j-2}(1-\frac{k}{n})}=(1-\prod_{k=1}^{x-1}(1-\frac{k}{n}))\sum_{j=1}^{x-1}\frac{1-\prod_{i=j+1}^{y-1}(1-\frac{i}{n})}{\frac{j}{n}\prod_{k=1}^{j-1}(1-\frac{k}{n})}$$
Edit: I corrected a mistake I made while writing it down.

I used $$P(X(n)\leq x)=1-P(X(n)> x)=1-\prod_{k=2}^{x}(1-\frac{k-1}{n})=1-\prod_{k=1}^{x-1}(1-\frac{k}{n})$$
$$P(X(n)=j)=\frac{j-1}{n}\prod_{k=2}^{j-1}(1-\frac{k-1}{n})=\frac{j-1}{n}\prod_{k=1}^{j-2}(1-\frac{k}{n})$$, where $\frac{j-1}{n}$ is the chance to draw a repeat in draw number jth, because $j-1$ unique integers have been drawn so far. $1-\frac{k}{n}$ is the chance to draw a unique number in draw number $k+1$.
For the last part, if j is the first repeat, there can't be a second repeat in the first jth draws:
$$P(Y(n)\leq y,X(n)=j)=1-\prod_{i=j+1}^{y}(1-\frac{i-1}{n})=1-\prod_{i=j}^{y-1}(1-\frac{i}{n})$$

Is this so far correct?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! You can get the proper font and spacing for $\min$ using `\min`. For operators that don't have a command of their own, you can use `\operatorname{name}`. Also, math mode isn't intended for italicizing text; as you can see here, it yields the wrong spacing for that. Usually text is italicized by enclosing it in asterisks. If you want to italicize text within math mode, you can use `\mathit{...}`. In the present case, there doesn't seem to be a need to italicize the text; in that case you can use `\text{...}` to include roman text in math mode.

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adjust to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/)'s a tutorial and reference for typesetting math on this site.